# Blue Prism fails to highlight Java application components

Tags: java, spy, blueprism

I am dealing with a peculiar issue.

After spying on a Java GUI that I have made (this might be important or it might not!), I am able to highlight correctly the components of the window.

But when I close the window and then open it again, it fails twice to highlight any component and then it highlights them correctly from that point on.

In order to spy on the elements I have used the Java Mode (I assume that this based on the Java Access Bridge).

Also, when I try to Open Application Navigator, but that also failed, although I have pasted the related files from the java access bridge.

It is really weird and there seems to be no easy answer for my problem.

Comment: Speaking to my limited experience with the Java Access Bridge, I'd suggest re-spying an element to a new entry in the Application Modeler when the original isn't highlighting correctly, and comparing the attributes and "Match?" checkboxes to find any differences.

Comment: I've seen stuff like element's attribute Name changing after you click somewhere, either what @esqew said or use some tool like Google's Access Bridge Explorer to find out what is going on there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something specific to Java, and is observed for many applications. Check whether the application needs to load some data from a backend server to function properly. The UI elements of the application might get loaded quickly, however some their attributes might still be loading from a backend server, and until it is full loaded the attributes would not match with the values you captured.